button in touch GFX
,
I want to be able to change the state of the button shown in the above picture, which is designed with TouchGFX, using the physical buttons on my microcontroller board. How can this be implemented?

According to the documentation, the functions getState() and forceState() will allow you to read the current state of the button and force it to the opposite state. This can be triggered by any other event in your system, including a physical button push.
It took me about 30 seconds to find this information online. Did you do any research on your own before asking here?

Hello, have good time dear friend,
Yes, I did some research before asking and was able to switch between the two pages using the physical button. However, I am having trouble with this button on the screen and have not been able to fix the problem.                                                         I would appreciate any help you can provide in resolving this issue.

What does "having trouble with this button on the screen" mean?

I want to map a physical button to control the on/off function of the graphical button on the LCD.
